# initState() not called on rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I got my build method like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: new NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              someWidget()
            ];
          },
          controller: _scrollController,
          body: Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  child: (_input.length == 0
                      ? Center(child: Text('Lädt...'))
                      : MyCoolWidget(_input)
                ),
            ))
          ])),
    );
  }
```

Now on runtime there is this method that get's called sometimes:

```
void setInput(List<String> input) {
    setState(() {
      _input = input;
    });
}
```

which changes the `input`. Now I'd like to have the `MyCoolWidget` to rebuild as the widget depends on this `input`. So I call it in `setState`. I checked and the build method get's rebuild but I won't see the correct changes.

This is because my `MyCoolWidget`s `initState` is not called again. But there I calculate important things depending on the `input`. Is there a method in the Widget Lifecycle to override for this purpose that gets called on rebuild?

Like somewhere in between `initState` and when the `build` method is called from `setState`:
[image: https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/12/flutter-lifecycle-widgets.html]

Image from: https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/12/flutter-lifecycle-widgets.html

Thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**
I did a workaround now myself. I added a flag to `MyCoolWidget` which I can set. This flag indicates if I need to recalculate the stuff I normally do in `initState`. When the `build()`-Method is called I check if this flag is set and decide to recalculate or not.

But maybe there is a better solution for my problem out there.

Comment: initState calls once when start the widget's lifecycle. if you need to calculate the value before the build(), you may consider to override the didChangeDependencies.

Comment: @CbL yeah..problem is, that `didChangeDependencies` is not called after `setState`

Comment: tried to override `State.didUpdateWidget`?

Comment: Then it is weird. didChangeDependencies is called when state is change. If the setstate is called, the state should be changed. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `didUpdateWidget`. From the [official documentation on this method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html):

> Called whenever the widget configuration changes.
>
> Override this method to respond when the widget changes (e.g., to
> start implicit animations).
>
> The framework always calls build after calling didUpdateWidget, which
> means any calls to setState in didUpdateWidget are redundant.

In your case, you can see it as if the framework called this method whenever the objects that your widget is receiving from its constructor change. It also provides you with the values of the `oldWidget` so you can update whatever you need conditionally.

You can override this method to implement the changes you want to make when your `input` changes, and Flutter will call the method whenever `input` is changed inside the `setState` of a parent widget.